# How to click a svg with title using cypress?

Tags: cypress

i am new to react and i am trying to click a svg with title cross. below is the dom structure

```
<div>
    <span data-testid="file">filename</span>
    <button type="button">
        <svg>
            <title>cross</title>
            <path></path>
        </svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

I am not sure how to do it. could someone help me with this. i want to click svg whose title is cross using cypress. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command `cy.contains(selector, content)`.

Here's my test. To run it install the [cypress-fiddle](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-fiddle) library

```
/// <reference types="@cypress/fiddle" />

const test = {
  html: `
  <div>
    <span data-testid="file">filename</span>
    <button type="button">
      <svg>
        <title>cross</title>
        <path></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
  `,
  test: `
    cy.contains('svg', 'cross').click()
  `
}
it('run test', () => {
  cy.runExample(test)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

`cy.get('svg title').contains('cross').click()`

or
`cy.contains('cross').click()`

Reference [link](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Content)

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this

```
const sele='button[type="button"]>svg';
cy.get(sele).click()
```